# Page size correction in horizontal scrolling using Javascript

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use page correction (for different browsers on different resolutions) in a horizontal scrolling website using scroll.js. Here's my code for page correction:

```
function getPageSize() {
    var de = document.documentElement;
    var w = window.innerWidth || self.innerWidth || (de && de.clientWidth) || document.body.clientWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight || self.innerHeight || (de && de.clientHeight) || document.body.clientHeight;
    arrayPageSize = [w, h];
    return arrayPageSize;
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    var page = getPageSize();
    var x = page[0];
    var y = page[1];
    $(".slide1").css({
        width: (x) + 'px'});
    $(".slide2").css({
        width: (x) + 'px'});
```

In my code, i'm trying to set the `width` of `slide1` and `slide2` equal to the `browser width`. 
My question is : is there any short way of doing this or I will have to repeat the same code for all the `slide`s?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using classes:

Just declare your classes (like .slide) with css to be width 100%

```
.slide
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

You don't necessarily need to accomplish this with javascript, this is what css is built for :)